# How to perform rotation before translation in tf2?

Tags: ros, tf2, translation, transformations, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Given the rpy values and some translational values , how to perform rotation before translation and then publish while using the tf2 library in ros

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260849/how-to-perform-rotation-before-translation-in-tf2?/) by [nikhilk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30103/nikhilk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-05-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2017-05-02**:
Both the C++ and Python tutorials have an example of converting RPY into a quaternion and broadcasting that transform. Do you have a specific question beyond what is covered in the tutorials? [C++ tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf2%20broadcaster%20%28C%2B%2B%29)

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2017-05-02**:
[Python tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf2%20broadcaster%20%28Python%29)

**Comment by [nikhilk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30103/nikhilk/) on 2017-05-03**:
yes, actually i am trying to get a frame which is rotated by given rpy values and then translated, hc's solution worked for me (point 1). Thank you guys :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I understand what you mean. You want to translate in the rotated frame and not the original frame. Unfortunately tf2 only works with translation and rotation being published with respect to the original frame. Because it is a transform with respect to that particular frame.

To solve your problem there are two ways:

1. The simple way is to create two
   frames. A temporary frame which
   contains only the rotation.  And
   then another transform to translate
   in this frame.
2. If you do not want to create a
   temporary frame, you can  calculate
   what the translational vector will
   be in the rotated frame. And then
   use those values instead.  To
   illustrate: If you want to first
   rotate by `r,p,y` and then translate
   in the rotated frame by `a,b,c`. You
   should calculate the new
   translational values `R * {a,b,c}`
   where `R` is the rotation matrix constructed by the rotation angles.
   Then you can use the tf2 package with these new values.

Hope this helps!

---

Originally posted by [hc](https://answers.ros.org/users/27378/hc/) with karma: 114 on 2017-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nikhilk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30103/nikhilk/) on 2017-05-03**:
Got it , thank you :)